# How to fill in Line 6 on Form 1040 if Schedule D does not have to be filed?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, form-1040x

In the United States, IRS [Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-dft/f1040--dft.pdf), line 6 is for Capital Gains. The instructions on the form say:

> Capital gain or (loss). Attach Schedule D if required. If not
>   required, check here

In order to determine whether Schedule D must be filed, I consult the [Instructions for Schedule 1040](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-dft/i1040gi--dft.pdf), where on page 27 the condition is found:

> If you sold a capital asset, such as a stock or bond, you must
>   complete and attach Form 8949 and Schedule D.

However in the following paragraphs an exception is provided to this condition:

> You don’t have to file Form 8949 or Schedule D if you
>   aren’t deferring any capital gain by investing in a qualified
>   opportunity zone fund and both of the following apply.
>   1. You have no capital losses, and your only capital gains are capital gain distributions from Form(s) 1099-DIV, box 2a (or substitute
>   statements); and
>   2. None of the Form(s) 1099-DIV (or substitute statements) have an amount in box 2b (unrecaptured section 1250 gain), box 2c (section
>   1202 gain), or box 2d (collectibles (28%) gain

No further instructions are provided on how to complete line 6. What goes into line 6 if the exception applies? Would one just add up all amounts from all forms 1099-DIV, box 2a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remaining instructions are further down the page, just past Exception 2:

> If Exception 1 applies, enter your total capital gain distributions (from 
>   box 2a of Form(s) 1099-DIV) on line 6 
>   and check the box on that line. If you received capital gain distributions as a 
>   nominee (that is, they were paid to you 
>   but actually belong to someone else), report on line 6 only the amount that belongs to you. Include a statement showing the full amount you received and the 
>   amount you received as a nominee. See 
>   the Schedule B instructions for filing requirements for Forms 1099-DIV and 
>   1096.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. I read the whole thing at least 5 times.